# Grid field, type file, won't upload svgs using {exp:channel:form}

Tags: error

I have set the "File Upload Preferences" set to "all file types", on the grid field i have  Allowed file type  set to "All".  I have the "Channel Form Settings" "Allow Guest Posts" set to yes for that channel.

In the CP i can upload an svg, but not when using exp:channel:form, i can not upload an svg.  Using 2.9.3 and need to keep that version for now.  I have tried updating the config.php with $config['allowed_types'] = 'svg'; and add to the mimes.php, and nothing lets me upload .svg files from my form (i can upload pngs, jpgs, txt, etc. from that form). Seems to just be svg that gives me "There was a problem with one or more Grid fields".

Answer (score 0):

After all of that, the answer is to go to Admin >> Security and Privacy >> Security and Sessions and set "Apply XSS Filtering to Uploaded Files" to no.  I also had trouble uploading PDFs until i did this.  Now i can upload both from the exp:channel:form